# Improve NodeJS Application Performance without Code Changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, performance

My organization is currently facing a kind of unique, or at least frustraiting challenge. We are contracted to host a specific computational Javascript service in which we do not have the ability to alter the code. The code runs alright, however, there is a significant amount of pressure to improve the performance of the hosted services with minimal budgetary changes to accomodate hardware scaling.

We have written a wrapper function to handle caching and are currently ustilizing worker_threads to scale the application across multiple theads them combining and returning the results in the response. Recently we moved the service into a Debian based docker container and we did see a slight performance improvement from there but it was still single digit improvements. Today I stumbled upon BUN and while it looks interesting and i'll test it out, but I don't necessarily see it being some magic bullet for performance improvement for a compute-type workload. Is there anything I have missed in attempting to address the problem with a non-hardware solution?

Comment: "*We have written a wrapper function*" - so you *can* actually alter (some of) the code?

Comment: @Bergi The service we provide is to host their service i.e. the Javascript computation file they provide. How we host it is entirely up to us, hence writing a wrapper function to help scale the function.